# org.json.JSONException: Duplicate key "x" in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, json

I have the following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions>
  <bpmn2:process id="defaultPackage.NewProcess2">
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_1" name="StartProcess">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_1" name="User Task 1">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_2" name="User Task 2">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_1" name="end event">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
  </bpmn2:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_Process_1" bpmnElement="defaultPackage.NewProcess2">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_StartEvent_1" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="60.0" y="210.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_UserTask_1" bpmnElement="UserTask_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="50.0" width="110.0" x="165.0" y="205.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_UserTask_2" bpmnElement="UserTask_2">
        <dc:Bounds height="50.0" width="110.0" x="550.0" y="203.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_EndEvent_1" bpmnElement="EndEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="842.0" y="202.0"/>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

For each userTask node defined under `<bpmn2:process> </bpmn2:process>` tags, I want to get theire position which is defined by x, y coordinates, which are found under :

```
<bpmndi:BPMNShape id="BPMNShape_UserTask_1" bpmnElement="UserTask_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="50.0" width="110.0" x="165.0" y="205.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
```

inside `<bpmndi:BPMNDiagram></bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>` tags.

I want to append x, y coordinates to the JSON string I built to generate the attributes of every userTask node.

I tried the following code :

```
public static void generateChildNodesDefinitions(Node node) throws JSONException
    {
        if (node != null && node.hasChildNodes())
        {

            jw.key("nodes").array();

            NodeList childnodelist = node.getChildNodes();

            for (int k = 0; k < childnodelist.getLength(); k++)
            {
                Node childn = childnodelist.item(k);

                if (childn.hasAttributes() && childn.getNodeName() != "bpmn2:sequenceFlow")
                {

                    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) jsonValues.get(childn.getNodeName());

                    NamedNodeMap nnmchildnodes = childn.getAttributes();
                    //per cdo nyje duhet te krijoj nje json object
                    jw.object();


                    if (nnmchildnodes != null)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < nnmchildnodes.getLength(); j++)
                        {


                            Node nodeUid = nnmchildnodes.item(j);

                            if (nodeUid.getNodeName().equals("id"))
                            {
                                String uid = new UID().toString();

                                hmIDs.put(nodeUid.getNodeValue(), uid);

                                nodeUid.setNodeValue(uid);

                            }



                            jw.key(nodeUid.getNodeName()).value(nodeUid.getNodeValue());
                        }
                    }


                    if (list != null && !list.isEmpty())
                    {
    List<String> myXarray = new ArrayList<String>();
                        List<String> myYarray = new ArrayList<String>(); 

                        ArrayList<String> bpmnElements = getElementAttributes("bpmndi:BPMNShape", "bpmnElement");
                        for (int j = 0; j < bpmnElements.size(); j++)
                        {
                            String bpmnElement = bpmnElements.get(j);
                          if(childn.getNodeName().equals("bpmn2:userTask")){
                              ArrayList<String> idUserTask = getIds("bpmn2:userTask");


                              for(int l=0; l < idUserTask.size(); l++){
                                  if(idUserTask.get(l).equals(bpmnElement)){

                                      ArrayList<String> Xs = getElementAttributes ("dc:Bounds" , "x");
                                      ArrayList<String> Ys = getElementAttributes ("dc:Bounds" , "y");

                                      String x = Xs.get(j);
                                      String y = Ys.get(j); 
                                      myXarray.add(x);
                                      myYarray.add(y);

                                     }
                                  }
                          }
                        }

                                      jw.key("x").value(myXarray);
                                      jw.key("y").value(myYarray);

}
```

Comment: in the for loop insted of jw.key("x").value(x); and jw.key("y").value(y); use jw.key(l).value(x); and jw.key(l).value(y); and check the output

Comment: l is of type int and the method key(String) in the type JSONWriter is not applicable for the 
  arguments (int)

Comment: You're constructing the wrong thing.  What you should do is construct a separate Map for each userTask, insert x and y as values into the Map, then insert the Map into a single main List.  Other attributes can be inserted into the Map as needed, then the entire structure can be cleanly "serialized" into JSON.

Comment: I tried this but I got the same error ... maybe I wasn't defining correctly the Map for each userTask . Could you please help me ?

Comment: It's not that hard.  Create a List.  As you process each userTask, create a Map and insert it into the List.  Add whatever info you have for that userTask to the Map.  When you're done you have a List of Maps that will very nicely serialize into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you are setting the key `jw.key("x").value(x);jw.key("y").value(y);`for each iteration it will be like a duplicate .

so better to set the values of x to an array then `jw.key("x").value(yourXarray);jw.key("y").value(yourYarray);`

```
List<String> yourXarray = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int l=0; l<idUserTask.size(); l++){ 
    if(idUserTask.get(l).equals(bpmnElement)){
      ArrayList<String> Xs = getElementAttributes ("dc:Bounds" , "x");
       String x = Xs.get(j);
       yourXarray.add(x)
     }}
 jw.key("x").value(yourXarray);
```

Comment: the values of x are allready into an array: 
**ArrayList<String> Xs = getElementAttributes ("dc:Bounds" , "x");**
I understand that the problem is that for each iteration it duplikates x, but I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: what is your expecting json string? if it is something like this `"id": "UserTask_1" "name":"User Task 1","x":"165.0","y":"205.0", "x":"16.0","y":"20.0"` i think you cant do that because you have duplicate "x" and "y"

Comment: no i want it to be: 
{"id": "UserTask_1" "name":"User Task 1","x":"165.0","y":"205.0"} for the first userTask node and:
{"id": "UserTask_2" "name":"User Task 2","x":"550.0","y":"203.0"} for the second. For every node I put theire attributes into a Json array

Comment: please add some more code to you question like creating JSONObject JSONWriter and how your printing json string

Comment: I edited my code as you said (with a little difference, please check)  and now my output is: 
{"id":"UserTask_1","name":"User Task 1","x":["165.0","550.0"],"y":["205.0","203.0"],}
{"id":"UserTask_2","name":"User Task 2","x":["165.0","550.0"],"y":["205.0","203.0"],}

Comment: is it giving any error? where is your json object? how your defining it .

Comment: no it doesn't give any error , but it doesn't give the correct output. For the first user task node I want to get only the first element of myXarray and myYarray respectively, and for the second user task node I want to get the second element of myXarray and myYarray

Comment: I added some more code to show you how i create the json object.

Comment: your out put shows that it is something related to your looping or logic where you are parsing the xml. recheck your code and go with your previous code